# Pyplot claims that the Figure type does not have the attribute `add_subplot()`, but ONLY if the code is not in a class

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot, figure

The following code produces a canvas with two empty plots on it, which is exactly what it should do.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec


class MakerOfTwoEmptyPlots(object):

    def __init__(self):

        self.fig = plt.figure()
        self.gs = GridSpec(1, 2, figure=self.fig)

        self.fig.add_subplot(self.gs[0, 0])
        self.fig.add_subplot(self.gs[0, 1])


plotter = MakerOfTwoEmptyPlots()
plt.show()
```

However, if I run the exact same code outside of a class, like so:

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(1, 2, figure=fig)

fig.add_sublot(gs[0, 0])
fig.add_sublot(gs[0, 1])

plt.show()
```

I get the error `AttributeError: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'add_sublot'`, despite the code being essentially identical and `self.fig` and `fig` being of the same type (I checked in the debugger). This is deeply confusing! Anybody know what's going on here?

Since this seems like the kind of problem that might depend on it, I'm using Python 3.9.1, MatPlotLib 3.3.3, and IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2020.3.

Edit: As multiple people have pointed out, it was a simple typo. oops. Thanks for seeing what I could not.

Comment: `Figure` objects indeed have no `add_sublot` attribute.  They instead have `add_subplot`, as you used in the first code block.  See the difference?

Comment: That's a typo. `fig.sublot(gs[0,0])` p is missing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be `fig.subplot` not `fig.sublot`:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.gridspec import GridSpec

fig = plt.figure()
gs = GridSpec(1, 2, figure=fig)

fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 1])

plt.show()
```

[image]